# How to use decimal data type

Tags: c#, sql-server, type-conversion

I want to get value which exactly am giving,

The datatype I am using is `decimal` in C# and `numeric(18,8)` in SQL Server

Here is declaration in C#:

```
[Required]
[DataType("decimal(18, 8")]        
public decimal Lat { get; set; }
```

But while I am providing a value of `13.0777545125`, I get back a value of `13.07000000`.

I think there is a simple solution, but am missing something. Please anybody help me

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `DisplayFormat` in your model property.

```
 [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.##}")] 
 public decimal Lat { get; set; }
```

Check this link for more information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#SpecifierD

Comment: First of all I want to store it to database with what am giving, not for displaying.

Comment: @shanmugamI know but you store it to database use this and The above will output a number with up to 2 decimal places.you set as par your requirement

Comment: Thank you I used it, Am getting same result. I want to store 13.5555555 like this.